# vscode - identify all built-in PHP functions used in a code base

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

Is there a way in vscode to identify all built-in PHP functions/methods that have been called in the currently open app/workspace?

By "built-in" I mean calls to functions/methods that are defined in the PHP manual (str_replace, PDO::exec ...). And by "identify" I mean provide a list of all functions/methods, preferably with a list of where each call is made from within the code.

My use case for this is to help with refactoring legacy PHP applications that are running on an old version of PHP. By being able to easily list all function calls it would be easier to identify deprecated code and prioritize the refactoring.

Alternatively, some way of listing the methods outside of vscode would also be an acceptable.

Thanks

Tony

Comment: You wanna look at extensions, personally I use [Intelephense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client)

Comment: I would go about this the opposite way. Work through the [PHP migration guides](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration81.php) See navigation on the right for the version to version release notes. You don't have to identify *all* calls to built-in PHP functions, just the ones who have changed in behavior.

Comment: Thanks @CanO'Spam. I'm using Intelephense and it does help identify deprecated/removed functions. Not fully what I'm hoping for in terms of a single view of all PHP internals used in a project, but a good nad partial solution.

Comment: Thanks @PeterKrebs. I'm planning on using the migration guides, as you sugeest. I was just imaging short-cutting some of the work by having a single view/list of all functions bring used -ideally with indicators of any which are deprecated/removed from the version of PHP on the local environment. I like the idea of having global view of how the code base is structured from a PHP-internals perspective - similar to the Outline feature or how the seach results are presented.   Perhaps this is an extension I need to consider building and contributing :)

Comment: Yes maybe you need to create that plugin. Could static PHP analysis tools help there, like PHPStan or Psalm?

Comment: How about `https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser` and check for `Expr_FuncCall`?

Comment: Thanks @PeterKrebs, I've not heard of those, I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks @qrsngky, that looks really interesting.